How to use S3 kafka Connector Freely
I'm learning Kafka and creating a POC where I need to sink Kafka topics data to S3 and from S3 to Kafka(another cluster).
I see connectors are there from confluent but seems those are commercialized and I don't want to pay now for a POC, is there any non-commercial process available ? I do not want create my own Kafka connector.

Here's the GitHub project for the connector under their community licence. I don't know the full details of the licence but looks like you can use it for your proof of concept at least.

This question is similar to: How to connect Apache Kafka with Amazon S3?. (I know you're asking "free", but that would still be closed under the "asking for an off-site resource" reason, so I think duplicate is better.)

The S3 source connector from Confluent has a paid license, but there may be alternatives. The Sink is source available
